# How can I write better SQL statement for data validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I am writing a stored procedure. Inside of it, I have data validations that are using if conditions. For example, if the first condition is success I call a stored procedure. If the if condition fails I call another stored procedure. Likewise I have more than 20 conditions to run in one stored procedure. And this creates performance issue. How can I write in a better way for the below scenario.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample 
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ModeClass = 'I'
    BEGIN 
        --Validation 001
        IF EXISTS (SELECT rderNumber FROM OrderHeader WHERE OrderNumber = @OrderNumber) 
            SET @STATE_H001 = 0;
            SET @FatalCode ='H001';
            SET @FatalFlag = 'F';
            EXEC spLinkTrackOrderProcessingResult 
                                                @pross, @RunningID, @BatchNumber, @FatalFlag, @RecordType, @OrderNumber,
                                                @Sequence1, @Sequence2, @CustomerCode, @Customerabbreviation, @LoadPlanNumber, @InvoiceNumber,
                                                @JobPlaningNumber,  @CompanyCode,   @PlantAbbreviation, @ModeClass,             @FieldName,         @BeforeChangeValue,
                                                @AfterChangeValue,  @FatalCode,     @FatalMessage,      @HeaderErrorFlag,       @DetailErrorFlag,   @ProcessUser,
                                                @ProcessDate,       @SolvedUser,    @SolvedDate,        @CreateUser,            @CreateDate,        @ChangeUser, 
                                                @ChangeDate,        @ByProgram,     @ByMachine;
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @STATE_H001 = 1;
            END

        --Validation 002
        IF EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1  FROM OrderDetail WHERE OrderNumber = @OrderNumber) 
            BEGIN
                SET @STATE_H004 = 1;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @STATE_H004 = 0;
                SET @FatalCode ='H004';
                SET @FatalFlag = 'F';
                EXEC spLinkTrackOrderProcessingResult 
                                                    @pross,             @RunningID,     @BatchNumber,       @FatalFlag,             @RecordType,        @OrderNumber,
                                                    @Sequence1,         @Sequence2,     @CustomerCode,      @Customerabbreviation,  @LoadPlanNumber,    @InvoiceNumber,
                                                    @JobPlaningNumber,  @CompanyCode,   @PlantAbbreviation, @ModeClass,             @FieldName,         @BeforeChangeValue,
                                                    @AfterChangeValue,  @FatalCode,     @FatalMessage,      @HeaderErrorFlag,       @DetailErrorFlag,   @ProcessUser,
                                                    @ProcessDate,       @SolvedUser,    @SolvedDate,        @CreateUser,            @CreateDate,        @ChangeUser, 
                                                    @ChangeDate,        @ByProgram,     @ByMachine;
            END
      END 
END
GO
```

Comment: The set based approach to validation is to write a query which validates multiple conditions in one go.

Comment: Ignoring the incomplete and invalid sql, define "better". IMO this approach is very unusual but no one knows what exactly you are trying to accomplish (NB **what**, not **how**). In addition, no one but you knows what your "performance condition" means. But I'll guess that you use the validation logic in a RBAR fashion (as part of an ETL process) and that is the source of your performance problems.

Comment: If you need to run a stored procedure for each condition, then you will have a big performance problem.  There might be a more holistic approach that uses no stored procedures at all.  That is just a suggestion, because your question does not have enough information to say more.

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue is because of the complexity of your execution plan. Reorganize your validation to call the logger SP only once with your validation result and do not use else clauses.

Example based on your code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample 
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ModeClass = 'I'
    BEGIN 
        SET @STATE_H001 = 1;
        SET @STATE_H004 = 1;
        --Validation 001
        IF EXISTS (SELECT rderNumber FROM OrderHeader WHERE OrderNumber = @OrderNumber) 
        BEGIN
            SET @STATE_H001 = 0;
            SET @FatalCode ='H001';
            SET @FatalFlag = 'F';
        END;

        --Validation 002
        IF @STATE_H001 = 1 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1  FROM OrderDetail WHERE OrderNumber = @OrderNumber) 
        BEGIN
                SET @STATE_H004 = 0;
                SET @FatalCode ='H004';
                SET @FatalFlag = 'F';
        END;
    END 
      
    if @STATE_H001 = 0 or @STATE_H004 = 0
        EXEC spLinkTrackOrderProcessingResult 
            @pross, @RunningID, @BatchNumber, @FatalFlag, @RecordType, @OrderNumber,
            @Sequence1, @Sequence2, @CustomerCode, @Customerabbreviation, @LoadPlanNumber, @InvoiceNumber,
            @JobPlaningNumber,  @CompanyCode,   @PlantAbbreviation, @ModeClass,             @FieldName,         @BeforeChangeValue,
            @AfterChangeValue,  @FatalCode,     @FatalMessage,      @HeaderErrorFlag,       @DetailErrorFlag,   @ProcessUser,
            @ProcessDate,       @SolvedUser,    @SolvedDate,        @CreateUser,            @CreateDate,        @ChangeUser, 
            @ChangeDate,        @ByProgram,     @ByMachine;
    
END
GO
```